# How to extract specific number from a string in R

Tags: r, regex

My data is look like this: x = when,ch_d_mean,< , 29.55
I want to extract 29.55 from x.

```
x = 'when,ch_d_mean,< , 29.55'
```

I want to have the value 29.55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `parse_number` from `readr`

```
library(readr)
parse_number(x)
#[1] 29.55
```

---

or with `str_extract` from `stringr

```
as.numeric(str_extract(x, "[0-9.]+"))
#[1] 29.55
```

---

Or with `gsub` from base R

```
as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]+", "", x))
#[1] 29.55
```

---

Or using `substring` from base R

```
as.numeric(substring(x, nchar(x)-4))
#[1] 29.55
```

NOTE: The last approach is based on the position if it is at the end of the string and occupies last 5 position

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have a further question. What if my data have the following form. x = 'when, ch_d_mean,>=, 29.55, &, ch_d_mean,< ,0.1090' How could I extract those two numbesr? Many thanks.

Comment: @H.Hsiao  Instead of `str_extract` use `as.numeric(str_extract_all(x, "[0-9.]+")[[1]])`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R option:

```
x <- "when,ch_d_mean,< , 29.55"
regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?", x))[[1]]

[1] "29.55"
```

Note that this approach is robust with regard to capturing any quantity of numbers in the input string.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility. You can then proceed with removing any extra white space.

```
x = 'when, ch_d_mean,>=, 29.55, &, ch_d_mean,< ,0.1090'     
res<-unlist(strsplit(x,","))
res[grep("[0-9]",res)]
#[1] " 29.55" "0.1090"
```